# Why is this program hanging?

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I have code that communicates between channels in Go. It appears to complete the desired operations, but it hangs at the end. I'm trying to diagnose why it is hanging.

The code is using `httpbin.org` to GET a random UUID, then post it, while obeying concurrency and rate limits that I have established via a semaphore channel and a rate channel.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type HttpBinGetRequest struct {
    url string
}

type HttpBinGetResponse struct {
    Uuid       string `json:"uuid"`
    StatusCode int
}

type HttpBinPostRequest struct {
    url  string
    uuid string // Item to post to API
}

type HttpBinPostResponse struct {
    Data       string `json:"data"`
    StatusCode int
}

func main() {

    // Prepare GET requests for n requests
    var requests []*HttpBinGetRequest
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        uri := "https://httpbin.org/uuid"
        request := &HttpBinGetRequest{
            url: uri,
        }
        requests = append(requests, request)
    }

    // Create semaphore and rate limit for the GET endpoint
    getSemaphore := make(chan struct{}, 10)
    getRate := make(chan struct{}, 10)
    defer close(getRate)
    defer close(getSemaphore)
    for i := 0; i < cap(getRate); i++ {
        getRate <- struct{}{}
    }

    go func() {
        // ticker corresponding to 1/nth of a second
        // where n = rate limit
        // basically (1000 / rps) * time.Millisecond
        ticker := time.NewTicker(100 * time.Millisecond)
        defer ticker.Stop()
        for range ticker.C {
            _, ok := <-getRate
            if !ok {
                return
            }
        }
    }()

    // Send our GET requests to obtain a random UUID
    respChan := make(chan HttpBinGetResponse)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for _, request := range requests {
        wg.Add(1)
        // cnt := c
        // Go func to make request and receive the response
        go func(r *HttpBinGetRequest) {
            defer wg.Done()

            // Check the rate limiter and block if it is empty
            getRate <- struct{}{}
            // fmt.Printf("Request #%d at: %s\n", cnt, time.Now().UTC().Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z07:00"))
            resp, _ := get(r, getSemaphore)

            fmt.Printf("%+v\n", resp)
            // Place our response into the channel
            respChan <- *resp
            // fmt.Printf("%+v,%s\n", resp, time.Now().UTC().Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z07:00"))
        }(request)
    }

    // Set up for POST requests 10/s
    postSemaphore := make(chan struct{}, 10)
    postRate := make(chan struct{}, 10)
    defer close(postRate)
    defer close(postSemaphore)
    for i := 0; i < cap(postRate); i++ {
        postRate <- struct{}{}
    }

    go func() {
        // ticker corresponding to 1/nth of a second
        // where n = rate limit
        // basically (1000 / rps) * time.Millisecond
        ticker := time.NewTicker(100 * time.Millisecond)
        defer ticker.Stop()
        for range ticker.C {
            _, ok := <-postRate
            if !ok {
                return
            }
        }
    }()

    // Read responses as they become available
    for ele := range respChan {
        postReq := &HttpBinPostRequest{
            url:  "https://httpbin.org/post",
            uuid: ele.Uuid,
        }
        go func(r *HttpBinPostRequest) {
            postRate <- struct{}{}
            postResp, err := post(r, postSemaphore)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
            fmt.Printf("%+v\n", postResp)
        }(postReq)

    }
    wg.Wait()
    close(respChan)
}

func get(hbgr *HttpBinGetRequest, sem chan struct{}) (*HttpBinGetResponse, error) {

    // Add a token to the semaphore
    sem <- struct{}{}

    // Remove token when function is complete
    defer func() { <-sem }()
    httpResp := &HttpBinGetResponse{}
    client := &http.Client{}
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", hbgr.url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error making request")
        return httpResp, err
    }

    req.Header = http.Header{
        "accept": {"application/json"},
    }

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        fmt.Println("error getting response")
        return httpResp, err
    }

    // Read Response
    body, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error reading response body")
        return httpResp, err
    }
    json.Unmarshal(body, &httpResp)
    httpResp.StatusCode = resp.StatusCode
    return httpResp, nil
}

// Method to post data to httpbin
func post(hbr *HttpBinPostRequest, sem chan struct{}) (*HttpBinPostResponse, error) {

    // Add a token to the semaphore
    sem <- struct{}{}
    defer func() { <-sem }()
    httpResp := &HttpBinPostResponse{}
    client := &http.Client{}
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", hbr.url, bytes.NewBuffer([]byte(hbr.uuid)))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error making request")
        return httpResp, err
    }

    req.Header = http.Header{
        "accept": {"application/json"},
    }

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error getting response")
        return httpResp, err
    }

    // Read Response
    body, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error reading response body")
        return httpResp, err
    }
    json.Unmarshal(body, &httpResp)
    httpResp.StatusCode = resp.StatusCode
    return httpResp, nil
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading from `respChan` at the end of your code via a `range` statement. This code will not exit until the channel is closed - which happens after that code block.

```
for ele := range respChan {
    // ...
}


wg.Wait()        
close(respChan)
```

So the program will never exit - since all this logic is within the same goroutine.

To fix - and ensure all records are processed before program exit - keep the channel reading code in the main goroutine and put the wait/close logic in it's own goroutine:

```
go func() {
    wg.Wait()        // wait for workers to finish ...
    close(respChan)  // ... now signal the main goroutine we're done
}()

for ele := range respChan {
    // ...
}
```

---

*EDIT* to wait for any sub-goroutines within the final `range` loop - there's probably a cleaner way to use just one waitgroup, but one quick fix could be:

```
var swg sync.WaitGroup

go func() {
    wg.Wait()        // wait for workers to finish ...
    swg.Wait()       // ... and sub-tasks
    close(respChan)  // ... now signal the main goroutine we're done
}()

for ele := range respChan {
    // ...
    swg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer swg.Done()
        // ...
    }()
}
```

Comment: thank you. when you say keep the channel reading in the main go routine, I purposefully have it separated so that the responses can create their own goroutines to send to the 2nd endpoint. I wanted to separate that logic from being goroutines nested in goroutines. I guess I'm a little confused on how putting it in the main go routine. are you referring to my first set of goroutines or the 2nd ones (starting with ```go func(r *HttpBinpostRequest)```

Comment: Depends on your use case. If it's a service - then there's no issue. If this is a discreet tool that runs & then exits, you have to be mindful that the program may exit while non-main goroutines are still running. If this is your case, then you need to ensure those satellite goroutines have finished too prior to program exit.

Comment: works like a charm and thanks for the additional info. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Coldchain9 added a quick edit on how one might wait for these sub-goroutines